# how to get facebook user email address on log in?

Tags: php

i have integrated facebook connect to my site. I want that whenever user logs in i should get his email address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have them grant you the email permission in your connect.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Once they do that, you can access it via the graph api, it's in the user object:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/